# How do you export a project from Blender to Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

This is what it looks like in blender:

[image: Blender screenshot]

and this is what it looks like after being exported to unity:

[image: Unity Screenshot]

The above is what results after only dragging the .blend file into the unity Assets folder, that's all I did. In Blender all the objects have only one Material with a single color or a single texture, so there's no complicated Materials. And in Unity I tried the "Extract Materials" option and it does nothing; and the "Extract Textures" option is greyed out.

I want it to look the same in Blender and Unity. Can someone point me in the right direction? I don't even know what to google anymore.

Comment: That colored texture in the back - is that a real texture or is that a shader-generated pattern? Because it looks like voronoi texture. You'd have to bake it, or create a Shadergraph in Unity to recreate the effect.

Comment: Yes it's the voronoi texture :)

Comment: @KYL3R What about the fidget popper? How do I make it look more like Blender?

Comment: For the popper, I would create a new Material in Unity and make it more shiny by lowering the roughness. And choose an HDRI for your scene as a background, so you get some reflections.

Comment: So there's no way to just export it as is from blender? Everything has to be redone?

Comment: Shaders in Blender are different from those in Game Engines, usually more expensive to render (Blender not made for realtime rendering). You can model in Blender, but need to create Materials and Shaders in Unity to get the desired look. The Material importer in Unity only supports single-color Materials and Textures I think. So you cannot reuse your Blender Nodes in Unity.

Comment: I know, it's just the Blender tutorial that I was following said that the Eevee renderer is similar to what's used in games, which now after googling it turns out to not be true. So I guess if I want to use Blender for video game assets then I can only create white meshes with it?

Comment: Depends. You can create a Donut and bake the texture to it. Then you have a 3D object, let's say .obj and the .mat with the Texture. That can be imported in every game engine (may need a few clicks) and can be used with the default Lit material.
If you want to sell Assets on Unity Asset Store, I would recommend you also deliver Unity Shaders (URP, HDRP, maybe builtin - yes it's horrible currently, having to support 3 Render Pipelines...) and a demo Scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite easy to recreate that in Unity.
[image: Recreated in Unity]

ShaderGraph also has a "Voronoi" Node, which is very similar. Instead of a Color-Ramp (Blender) I sampled a Gradient.
[image: ShaderGraph Nodes]

For the fidget popper, I used a HDRP/Lit Shader on a new Material and just set Color, Metallic and Smoothness.

[image]

Comment: How did you do it so fast :O